# TURN server doesn't response TCP relay candidate

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I setup turnserver 3.2.5.9 for WebRTC

I'd like to do this.

```
Client-A-->(TCP)-->TURN-->(UDP)-->TURN-->(TCP)-->Client-B
```

I have tow problems each Client-A and B ,both in different private network each other.

For the Client-A's issue.

The TURN server responds candidates for `host` `srfix` `relay`.

I'd like have a `relay` candidate as `tcp`.

However,I only can have `udp` .

How can I have a `relay` candidate as `tcp`.

For the Client-B's issue.

The TURN server responds only `host`.

So, the Client-B can't have any access to the TURN server.

FW policy, which Client-B is placed, is strict that it isn't allow to use `UDP`.

However, I think It should access to the TURN server by TCP.

Does anyone know how to tell the TURN server about Clients' Global IPs and TCP ports in both cases.

Here is turnserver.conf

```
listening-port=80
listening-ip=my-server-global-ip
external-ip=my-server-global-ip
lt-cred-mech
userdb=/opt/turnserver/etc/turnuserdb.conf
realm=my.server.domain
stale-nonce
no-udp
no-stun
```

Here is Response from [Trickle ICE tool](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) at the Client-A

```
Time    Component   Type    Foundation  Protocol    Address Port    Priority
0.015   1   host    2508812977  udp 10.2.1.17   53175   126 | 32542 | 255
0.059   1   srflx   3607399481  udp Client-Global-ip    53175   100 | 32542 | 255
0.086   1   relay   1628315121  udp my-server-global-ip 54043   1 | 32542 | 255
0.116   1   host    3674902081  tcp 10.2.1.17   9   90 | 32542 | 255
39.827  Done
39.833
```

Here is Response from [Trickle ICE tool](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) at the Client-B

```
0.012   1   host    1197209968  udp 192.168.95.131  60019   126 | 30 | 255
39.819  Done
39.823
```

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC does not support allocation of TCP relay candidates.
Note that you can still have TURN/TCP candidates which use TCP between the client and the TURN server, those will have a local type preference of 1 which you can see in the trickle ice tool output.

Comment: ,I'd like to know how to access to the TURN server  from the client with TCP connection. I edited my post to add what I really like to do.

Comment: The TURN url needs to look like `turn:host:port?transport=tcp`
You already seem to do so. based on the priorities you've shown.

Comment: I did `turn:host:port?transport=tcp` as you show.I think unless the candidate is tcp I'll never make TCP connection between the client and the TURN server.

Comment: ,According to the Server's messages,some tunnel between Client and the TURN server was once established.I found a message `TCP socket closed remotely Client-Global-ip`. However,I recognized another problem. Revised my post.

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-configure TURN server with TCP protocol option. Kurento and Wowza support TCP protocol for WebRTC.

Comment: It would be helpful to add links to docs , example etc.